# Misunderstanding in Java

Tags: java, class, static, field, non-static

I'm trying the static and non-static methods and fields.
I tried to compile this:

```
class main{
    public int a=10;
    static int b=0;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        b+=1; //here i can do anything with static fields.
    }
}

class bla {
    void nn(){
        main.a+=1; //why here not? the method is non-static and the field "main.a" too. Why?
    }
}
```

and the compiler returns me:

```
try.java:10: non-static variable a cannot be referenced from a static context
```

but why? The method and the field "a" are both non-static!

Comment: It would really help your cause to use standard naming convention of class names starting with a capital letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to access `a` in a static manner.  You will first need to instantiate `main` to access `a`.

```
main m = new main();
m.a += 1;
```

Also, for readability, you should capitalize the names of Classes, and camel case your instance variables.

Comment: I've tried but it can't find symbol: java:11: cannot find symbol symbol : variable m location: class main

Answer (score 2):

The variable `a` is NOT static and thus can not be accessed without an instance of `Main`

```
Main.b += 1; // This will work, assuming that your class is in the same package

Main main = new Main();
main.a += 1; // This will work because we can reference the variable via the object instance
```

So, lets assume we have the class

```
public class Main {

    public int a = 10;
    static int b = 0;

}
```

Now we come along with, assuming that the classes are in the same package

```
public class Blah {

    void nn() {

        Main.a += 1; // This will fail, 'a' is not static
        Main.b += 1; // This is fine, 'b' is static

        Main main = new Main();
        main.a += 1; // Now we can access 'a' via the Object reference

    }
}
```

Comment: `new Main(new String[0]);` ?  Really?  :-)  Bad MadProgrammer!

Comment: @RichardSitze That's, my brain as offically left the building :P +1 for the spot

Comment: @sleax 1. Make sure you're using the updated sample, RichardSitze was kind enough to peer review my example for me.  2. `a` is not a static reference, it can not be accessed without an instance of `main` (and both classes must exist within the same package). 3. Take the time to learn the Java recommened naming conventions (http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) it will reduce confusion over class/instance references :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of class main to change a since that is not a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized an instance of `main` in the `nn()` method.